# How to do a smooth vertical scrolling in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, lag, smooth-scrolling, smoothing

When tapping the screen, a ball bounces in the air and if it is above a certain heigh, I scroll the screen. In my case, the scrolling is not smooth all the time, there is some lagging, any idea to do it better? Thank you so much if you have a better or another idea!

Here is the code:

```
let world = SKNode()
var player : SKSpriteNode!
var firsttap = true

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -9.9)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    self.createPlayer()
    addChild(world)
    world.addChild(player)

    let floor = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: 320, 20))
    floor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: 320, 20))
    floor.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    floor.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), 0)

    addChild(floor)
}

func createPlayer() {
    self.player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
    let body = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:13.0)
    body.dynamic = false
    body.contactTestBitMask = PlayerCategory
    body.allowsRotation = false
    player.physicsBody = body
    player.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame) * 0.75)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        if firsttap {
            player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            firsttap = false
        } 
        let touchLoc = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var right = true
        if touchLoc.x > CGRectGetMidX(frame) {
            right = false
        }

        if right {
            player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
            player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-2, 14))
        }else{
            player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
            player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(2, 14))
        }
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    let pos : CGFloat = -player.position.y + CGRectGetMidY(frame)
    if pos < world.position.y {
        world.position.y = pos
    }
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let nextLevel = GameScene((size: frame.size))
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    view?.presentScene(nextLevel, transition:transition)
}
```

it happens to be smooth the first time but not the following ones when presenting the same scene and I don't understand why :(

Comment: Is it that way on a hardware device or just the simulator?